# Storing a collection of IWhatever in MongoDB via NoRM

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm, nosql

I'm having a very hard time getting this working; not even totally sure that it's possible.

Let's imagine a simple scenario:

```
class Employee {
   List<ITask> Tasks {get;set;}
}
```

And say we have two different implementations of tasks.

If I want to save the Employee object in MongoDB as a single document (the right way to do it I think), I'm getting completely stuck on being able to do any useful querying.  For instance, if a certain kind of ITask has categories and I want to pull ITasks in category A.  Or if a task is referenced in another document and I need to go pull it back.  I keep running into "not supported" problems (SelectMany, OfType) and then things go downhill from there.

Anyone have some insight on how to accomplish either of those scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Norm is no longer supported or maintained.
I would suggest you look at the official driver, especially at discriminators

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Polymorphicclassesanddiscriminators